# AWS ssh into instance giving Permission denied (publicly)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to ssh into a new EC2 instance. I have followed the instructions and when I attempt to ssh I get Permission denied (publickey).

Below is an image of everything I did in the console according to the instructions. Everything seems to go accordingly until I enter yes. Then it fails. I have followed the instructions twice and get the same result. I also do not have AWS CLI Tools as I believe they are optional.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh will use your local username to connect to the instance by default, if you not specified `Host`, `User` and `IdentityFile` in your ~/.ssh/config.

As you call ssh to your instance with the pem specified on the command line you also have to specify the remote user name (which is ec2-user for AWS linux instances and ubuntu for AWS Ubuntu instances).

Try to use this commandline:
`ssh -i sub_api.pem ec2-user@ec2-54....`

Comment: Thank you. I missed that in the example in the connect dialog.